# JQuery methods for posting to Web API 2

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

For starters, this is more of a question of "why," rather than how, but if someone has a better method for a universal post, I'd be grateful.

I have several different forms, and tables, that gather, and retrieve data from Web API, using JQuery.  The problem/question I have is why does it take two different methods of posting to my controllers, depending on the content?

The first method, which is also my most commonly used (and widely successful) routine:

```
        postService: function (funcLoc, postData, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                  dataType: 'json',
                  type: "POST",
                  data: postData,
                  url: siteName() + funcLoc,
                  success: function (data) {
                      if (data) {
                          if (callback) {
                              callback(data);
                          }
                      } else {
                          alert("something went wrong");
                      }
                  }
              });
    }
```

As you can see, this is just a common wrapper for what most would consider a standard JQ Ajax call.  This works for almost everything.  I can post data to it, and retrieve data, *MOST* of the time with something similar to this:

```
        var frmData = form.serializeObject();
        $(this).find("[id^=chk]").each(function () {
               frmData[$(this).prop("name")] = $(this).is(":checked");
         });
         frmData = App.addAntiforgery(frmData);
         DataManager.postService("/API/Settings", frmData, function () {
               $("#spinner").hide();
               $.bootstrapGrowl('Saved Site Settings', { type: 'success', delay: 5000 });
         });
```

The problem I've run into is when positing a list of data.  This method fails every time, and the method I created to handle lists, fails for everything else:

So let's take this example:

```
      var msgObj = new Object();
      msgObj.messages = Settings.newsList;
      var newsData = App.addAntiforgery(msgObj);
```

Where newsList is an array of objects.

In this case, I have found no possible way to get this post using "postService."  The only way I was able to get this to work was by adding the content type of application/json to a different function, and stringifying the data.  Here is that method:

```
    postList: function (funcLoc, postData, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(postData),
            url: siteName() + funcLoc,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(data);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("something went wrong");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

You'll have to excuse my ignorance here, but when I inspect both objects, they both appear generally the same (console.log(obj)).  They are both objects, as most of my application is comprised, but in ONE INSTANCE (posting a list/array of objects), I have to use the second method, as nothing I do with the first method will work.  Likewise, everything else won't work with the second method.

Here is the general signature I use in all my controllers:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public int Post([FromBody]tb_Sites value)
```

I know it's something obvious and simple I'm not seeing here, but I'm at a loss as to what it is.  Yes, I got it to work, but I don't like hacking things together and calling it a day, just because "they work."

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `tb_Sites` is? Is that a class with matching properties that should automatically bind to the data being sent? What is the signature when you send a list of objects, something like `List<tb_Sites>`? I tried to reproduce this and found that `postService()` does indeed work for objects but not arrays. But for me `postList()` is working for both.

Comment: It is simply an entity (from Entity Framework 4.6).  I was thinking postList should work for both as well, and perhaps I need to investigate further, as I may have missed something.  It is just that when I replace postService with the code from postList, everything starts failing.  The backend for the majority of the work being done for postService revolves around DataTables (javascript).